# catching the zoom out event

Tags: iphone, sdk

Can anybody tell me how to catch the zoom out event. My purpose is that i want to *disable the auto zoom in when the user zoom out*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only documented methods related to this are `mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:` and `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` on MKMapViewDelegate, which would be called on zoom out as well as zoom in and scroll.